# Google Maps API not working on Kubernetes deployment

Tags: laravel, google-maps, kubernetes, ssl-certificate

Laravel application deployed on Kubernetes and making requests to https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json failing with:

```
SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

The same application works when running on Docker.

I have appended Google's Root CA certs from here https://developers.google.com/maps/root-ca-faq#what_is_happening to the server's trust store but no luck there either.

I can disable verification but that's not the correct approach.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you make sure PHP is using the system certificate store? It may be that your dev environment is overriding the default path.

Comment: Hi @GonrasKarols, I'm mapping the server's certificate store in a volume in my deployment.yaml. It works for example to connect to MySQL over SSL. The strange thing is, I can search for an address and the map finds and show the address, but the error comes when I call the geocode endpoint to get the coordinates.

Comment: Hi @GonrasKarols, the issue was that our security team scans external certificates and re-package them with the company's own cert. Once I added the company's cert to the trust store, everything worked fine. It seems it's only an internal issue. Thanks for taking your time to have a go at it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

According to the OP, the solution was:

> The issue was that our security team scans external certificates and
> re-package them with the company's own cert. Once I added the
> company's cert to the trust store, everything worked fine. It seems
> it's only an internal issue.